Add the row counts as a list to column using groupby
I am working on an application that needs to provide the count of certain entries in a dataframe. Am I missing something that is not rendering the required outcome?
Input:
| Release   | Mapping | Coding |
|-----------|---------|--------|
| release_a | A1      | C2     |
| release_c | A1      | C2     |
| release_a | A1      | C2     |
| release_a | A1      | C1     |
| release_b | B       | C1     |
| release_c | B       | C2     |
| release_c | B       | C3     |
| release_a | C       | C1     |
| release_c | A1      | C1     |
| release_c | A1      | C3     |
| release_a | C       | C1     |

Outcome expected:
| Release   | Mapping      |
|-----------|--------------|
| release_a | A1 - 3, C-2  |
| release_b | B-1          |
| release_c | A1 -3, B - 2 |

Code used:
df.groupby(['Release', 'Mapping'])['Coding'].agg(count='count')

What I am getting:

Maybe I don't have a thorough understanding of how use the agg method. If there is any better alternative, please suggest it.

Here's an approach with collections.Counter:
from collections import Counter

out = (df.groupby('Release')['Mapping']
       .agg(lambda x: ", ".join(f"{k} - {v}" for k, v in Counter(x).items()))
       .reset_index()
       )

Output:
     Release        Mapping
0  release_a  A1 - 3, C - 2
1  release_b          B - 1
2  release_c  A1 - 3, B - 2

Or via Series.value_counts, but that seems to be slower:
out2 = (df.groupby('Release')['Mapping']
        .agg(lambda x: ", ".join(f"{k} - {v}" for k, v in x.value_counts()
                                 .items()))
        .reset_index()
        )

# out.equals(out2)
# True

Already on a small set like this, both will outperform using df.iterrows (and a double groupby) as suggested in the answer by @VinodBaste. Avoid it where you can, and in general you can (see here).
Timings:
# Counter
747 µs ± 25.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# value_counts
1.27 ms ± 40.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# iterrows
2.45 ms ± 48.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Data used
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Release': ['release_a', 'release_c', 'release_a', 'release_a', 'release_b', 
                'release_c', 'release_c', 'release_a', 'release_c', 'release_c', 
                'release_a'],
    'Mapping': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A1', 'A1', 'C'],
    'Coding': ['C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C1', 'C1', 'C3', 'C1']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

